# Hide specific element in a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown menu where i hide certain elements depending on what ad group they are in. 
My code hides the element if its on the bottom in the menu, not if the element is in the top of menu, then it hides every elements.

-- Site1 --

-- Site2 --

-- Site3 --

-- Site4 --

Heres my code:

This will hide every element:

```
 $('span:contains("Site1")').show();
 $('span:contains("Site2")').hide();
 $('span:contains("Site3")').hide();
 $('span:contains("Site4")').hide();
```

And if its "Site4" in the bottom of the menu, the code works.. (Only site4 will be visible)

```
 $('span:contains("Site1")').hide();
 $('span:contains("Site2")').hide();
 $('span:contains("Site3")').hide();
 $('span:contains("Site4")').show();
```

The html meny:

```
<ul class="dynamic" style="">

  <li class="dynamic">
   <a class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/test/site1">
    <span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow">
     <span class="menu-item-text">Site1</span>
    </span>
  </a>
 </li>

     <li class="dynamic">
   <a class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/test/Site2">
    <span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow">
     <span class="menu-item-text">Site2</span>
    </span>
  </a>
 </li>

     <li class="dynamic">
   <a class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/test/Site3">
    <span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow">
     <span class="menu-item-text">Site3</span>
    </span>
  </a>
 </li>

     <li class="dynamic">
   <a class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/test/Site4">
    <span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow">
     <span class="menu-item-text">Site4</span>
    </span>
  </a>
 </li>

 </ul>
```

Comment: Check your opening and closing of the Span tags.

Comment: what you mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Rasmus you have to post the markup of your dropdowns.

Comment: @Rasmus Edit the question and post the HTML for the Menu dropdpwn values

Comment: Now i posted the html edits

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, I have try to do the same stuff for you. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/ZyHnk/276/)

Html

```
<div id="1">
    <span class="name">
    <div class="quote">Mark</div>
        </span>
</div>

<div id="2">
    <span class="name1">
    <div class="quote1">Run</div>
        </span>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('.name .quote').hide();
$('.name1 .quote1').show();
```